# How to add dummy row based on one column in pandas dataframe?

Tags: python-2.7, pandas, dataframe, rows

I'm working with pandas,So basically i've two dataframes and the number of rows are different in both the cases:

## df

```
        wave  num  stlines     fwhm       EWs  MeasredWave  
0    4050.32    3  0.28269  0.07365  22.16080  4050.311360   
1    4208.98    5  0.48122  0.08765  44.90035  4208.972962   
2    4374.94    9  0.71483  0.11429  86.96497  4374.927110   
3    4379.74    9  0.31404  0.09107  30.44271  4379.760601   
4    4398.01   14  0.50415  0.09845  52.83236  4398.007473 
5    5520.50    1  0.06148  0.12556   8.21685  5520.484742
```

## df1

```
        wave  num  stlines     fwhm       EWs  MeasredWave  
0    4050.32    3  0.28616  0.07521  22.91064  4050.327388   
1    4208.98    6  0.48781  0.08573  44.51609  4208.990029   
2    4374.94    9  0.71548  0.11437  87.10152  4374.944513   
3    4379.74   10  0.31338  0.09098  30.34791  4379.778009   
4    4398.01   15  0.49950  0.08612  45.78707  4398.020367   
5    4502.21    9  0.56362  0.10114  60.67868  4502.223123   
6    4508.28    3  0.69554  0.11600  85.88428  4508.291777   
7    4512.99    2  0.20486  0.08891  19.38745  4512.999332
8    5520.50    1  0.06148  0.12556   8.21685  5520.484742
```

So there are some rows in `df1` that are not in `df`. So i want to add the row to the dataframe and reset the index accordingly. Previously i was just removing the extra rows from the dataframe to keep them equal but now i just want to add an empty row of the index of column isn't there.

The desired result should look like this,

```
        wave  num  stlines     fwhm       EWs  MeasredWave  
0    4050.32    3  0.28269  0.07365  22.16080  4050.311360   
1    4208.98    5  0.48122  0.08765  44.90035  4208.972962   
2    4374.94    9  0.71483  0.11429  86.96497  4374.927110   
3    4379.74    9  0.31404  0.09107  30.44271  4379.760601   
4    4398.01   14  0.50415  0.09845  52.83236  4398.007473 
5    4502.21    0       0      0         0         0   
6    4508.28    0       0      0         0         0   
7    4512.99    0       0      0         0         0
8    5520.50    1  0.06148  0.12556   8.21685  5520.484742
```

How can i get this?

Comment: What is about wave?  Based on your question should be 0 as well if is not the index.

Comment: yeah if the index of  column 'wave' isn't there then i want to put that index in the dataframe and all the values of all the other column of that row to be zero

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIUC, you can use `DataFrame.loc` to update the values of `df1` where `wave` doesnt exist in `df`:

```
df1.loc[~df1.wave.isin(df.wave), 'num':] = 0
```

Then use `DataFrame.combine_first` to make sure that the values in `df` take precedence:

```
df_out = df.set_index('wave').combine_first(df1.set_index('wave')).reset_index()
```

[out]

```
print(df_out)
      wave   num  stlines     fwhm       EWs  MeasredWave
0  4050.32   3.0  0.28269  0.07365  22.16080  4050.311360
1  4208.98   5.0  0.48122  0.08765  44.90035  4208.972962
2  4374.94   9.0  0.71483  0.11429  86.96497  4374.927110
3  4379.74   9.0  0.31404  0.09107  30.44271  4379.760601
4  4398.01  14.0  0.50415  0.09845  52.83236  4398.007473
5  4502.21   0.0  0.00000  0.00000   0.00000     0.000000
6  4508.28   0.0  0.00000  0.00000   0.00000     0.000000
7  4512.99   0.0  0.00000  0.00000   0.00000     0.000000
8  5520.50   1.0  0.06148  0.12556   8.21685  5520.484742
```

Comment: well, but there isn't any duplicates in the data then why should i add the first line of your code?? @chris

Comment: It only dedupes the values of wave form each DataFrame to give unique values

Comment: nah it didn't do anything.! I just appended all the rows of df1 to df

Comment: @GyanenderGandhar Apologies, I misunderstood at first. Does this updated version work for you?

Comment: @GyanenderGandhar Got there in the end :) Apologies again for the misunderstanding!

Comment: Haha yeah.! Thanks once again.!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/180126/discussion-between-gyanender-gandhar-and-chris-a).